# How to replace an image with mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am a new mxgraph user so my knowledge about mxgraph is very poor. I'll try to explain my problem as clear as possible: I want to replace an image with a new one using mxgraph. Is there a way to do that with mxgraph? I tried `graph.setCellStyles` function, or this way:

```
mxGraph.prototype.getImage = function(state)
{
  if (state != null && state.style != null)
  {
    return state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE];
  }
  return null;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Java solution:

```
graph.getView().getState(cell).getStyle().replace(mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE, new ImageIcon( GraphViewer.class.getResource("/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/images/cube_green.png")));
```